# Detect when a role is mentioned in a message in discord py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am looking for a piece of code that will detect when a discord role is @'ed. For example:

User: @Admin please help!
I just need the code that will detect 'Admin' role has been mentioned and trigger a few commands.

What I was thinking of was:

```py
@client.event
async_def onmessage(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content == "[role ID / name here]":
    print("[Role] has been mentioned")
```

I am currently using the Discord PY libery.

hope someone can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I'm not sure whether I have missed anything here but this seems to work. An original print statement added to the on_message function will reveal the id of the role you want to look for. Also for roles like @everyone or @here - they can be checked for in plaintext.

```
@client.event
async_def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if "<@&878031297270923384>" in message.content: # Replace with your role ID
    print("@Admin has been mentioned")
  # print(message.content) Find the role tag
```

Comment: absolutely fabulous! Works everysingle time. Love it

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the correct way of doing things, but one way you can do it is by checking if @Admin is in the message. That's how I check if someone pinged everyone.

```
@client.event
async_def onmessage(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  else:
        for word in message.content:
            if word == "@Admin":
                print("Admin has been mentioned")
```

It's not a permanent solution but it works

Comment: I'd recommend Matt Override's answer as it seems more refined